# Did Donald Duck accidentally use methylene in a comic before it was discovered?

Tags: chemistry

From [Good Comics](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2007/01/25/comic-book-urban-legends-revealed-87/):

> In 1963, the Disney Studio learned just how wide and faithful a
>   readership Barks had. A letter arrived from Joseph B. Lambert of the
>   California Institute of Technology, pointing out a curious reference
>   in “The Spin States of Carbenes,” a technical article soon to be
>   published by P.P. Gaspar and G.S. Hammond (in Carbene Chemistry,
>   edited by Wolfgang Kirmse, New York: Academic Press, 1964). “Despite
>   the recent extensive interest in methylene chemistry,” read the
>   article’s last paragraph, “much additional study is required…. Among
>   experiments which have not, to our knowledge, been carried out as yet
>   is one of a most intriguing nature suggested in the literature of no
>   less than 19 years ago (91).” Footnote 91, in turn, directed readers
>   to issue 44 of Walt Disney’s Comics and Stories. It seems Donald’s
>   reference to CH2 in panel 2.1 was years ahead of its time: the
>   existence of this elusive chemical intermediate had not been proven in
>   1944.

However, they also believe that a Donald Duck comic caused a patent for raising a ship from the bottom of the ocean to be rejected, which is [actually a myth](http://www.starch.dk/isi/kroyer/schrooge.asp).

Comment: Have I got this right? The claim is that the chemical gobbledygook that the comic writers put in the mouth of Donald Duck accidentally included a molecular formula, CH2, that wasn't actually shown to exist for 19 more years. Given Good Comics already have a reference to the paper and scan of the comic, what sort of evidence would it take to convince you this story is true or false?

Comment: @Oddthinking: I can't access the paper :-(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While I couldn't find an online version of the original paper,

> - *"**The Spin States of Carbenes. (No. 3036)**", P.P. Gaspar and G.S. Hammond, Chapter 12 in "Carbene Chemistry", Vol. 1. W. Kirmse, Editor, Academic Press, New York, pp 235-274 (1964)*

at least [it does exist](http://web.pdx.edu/%7Ewamserc/Hammond/pubs.htm).

But there is a reference to it in the textbook [**"Organic Chemistry"** *by Morrison and Boyd:*](http://pubs.acs.org/cen/education/83/8341education1.html)

> [image: Morrison & Boyd] <sup>[Source](http://pubs.acs.org/cen/education/83/8341education1.html)</sup>
>
> [image: Donald Duck] <sup>[Source](http://chemistress-sarah.blogspot.co.at/2009/12/comic-quackery.html)</sup>
>
> [image] <sup>[Source](http://llrc.mcast.edu.mt/digitalversion/Table_of_Contents_123857.pdf)</sup>

**More:**

- [The Periodic Table of Comic Books - Donald Duck](http://www.uky.edu/Projects/Chemcomics/html/dd_15_2_n.html)